# Does Electron have a standard way of killing a useless renderer process?

Tags: process, electron, chromium

My app creates a window with a local page that requires node integration to be enabled.

After I click a button on this page, I am navigated to a third party page.

Because I want node to be disabled in this third party page, and I can't toggle node integration in a `BrowserWindow`, I load this third party page in a sandboxed `BrowserView` that is embedded inside of the window and is stretched to fit the entire screen.

Now doing this navigates the embedded view, but the `BrowserWindow` is stuck pointing to the old local page that is no longer relevant.

To prevent this extra page from sitting around in the background, I navigate my `BrowserWindow` to `"about:blank"` to effectively clear it out and make room for the `BrowserView`.

I am realizing now that while this "clears" out the old page, it keeps the renderer process that's associated with it alive. From [here](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/process-models):

> Chromium creates a renderer process for each instance of a site the user visits

And understandably, navigating to `"about:blank"` doesn't signal to Electron that it should kill the other process.

I want to get rid of this renderer process, so it doesn't sit around unnecessarily and use CPU and memory when I interact with the window.

Two things that have worked:

I removed the extra navigation to `"about:blank"` since we're now killing the process and:

1) When my button in my renderer sends a message to the main process telling it to create a `BrowserView` and navigate to the new site, I do a `process.exit();`. I guess a part of me is nervous about the process exit interfering with the message that gets queued up for main, though it seems to work fine.

2) Instead of killing the process from the renderer, I created and navigated my `BrowserView` and then ran a little `browserWindow.webContents.executeJavascript("process.exit()");`. I find this uglier, though it does mitigate by concern above in #1.

There isn't a `webcontents.destroy()` type of method, and I don't know of a way to signal to Electron that it needs to destroy this unnecessary process.

I suppose I might have a pretty unique case, but is there a nicer way (or more standard way) of handling this than explicitly doing a `process.exit()`?

Comment: Have you tried `destroy()` method of `BrowserView`?

Comment: @Asesh I don't want to destroy the `BrowserView` though. That's the thing that I want to keep. I want to destroy the renderer that was created as a result of navigating the *window* (so like a window.webcontents.destroy() though that doesn't exist)

Comment: Do you realize that `BrowserView` represents a renderer, while `WebContents` represent a webpage?

Comment: @Asesh Hm my view has been that when we navigate a BrowserView or a BrowserWindow, *then* a renderer process gets created along with a valid webcontents. Maybe I'm wrong that destroying a webcontents will kill the process. In any case, I want to keep the renderer that's associated with the BrowserView alive. It's the other renderer that's created when navigating the BrowserWindow that I want to destroy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a [`WebContents::forcefullyCrashRenderer()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsforcefullycrashrenderer) API that accomplishes this (introduced by [this PR](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/25580)):

> Forcefully terminates the renderer process that is currently hosting this `webContents`. This will cause the `render-process-gone event` to be emitted with the `reason=killed || reason=crashed`. Please note that some webContents share renderer processes and therefore calling this method may also crash the host process for other webContents as well.

Answer (score 0):

As of now (July 2021, Electron v13) - there's also an undocumented `webContents.destroy()`.

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10096

As the documentation mentions, some webContents share renderer processes and if you use `webContents.forcefullyCrashRenderer()` you may terminate them as well.

I'm not sure about how `webContents.destroy()` handles it, but from the name it seems to be more narrow in scope. I would assume that it kills the renderer if webContents is the only webContents attached to it (I tested this) and spares the renderer if other webContents is using it (needs confirmation).